# Returning default/generic exception on optional orElseThrow

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I'm not sure about the title of my question but here's my problem. I have this code below:

```
return Optional.of(t).filter(p -> {
    PolicyNumber test = (PolicyNumber) p;

    return service.getAndValidate(p).test(p);
}).map(p -> {
    return p;
}).orElseThrow(() -> {
    return null;
});
```

The `getAndValidate` method works fine but when I get to the `map` block (is that what you call it?), an error is triggered. Before, I've been using `try...catch` and I can simply code something like:

```
try {
    //some code
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And with that, I can easily see what the commotion is all about. I was wondering how can I do this for the `Optional`. I'm quite new with it and I'm trying to be somewhat knowledgeable with it. I've checked tutorials online but most of what I see requires me to have a class with pre-determined messages to be used as Exception messages. If I simply use `return null;` obviously I won't get any error message and I won't learn what error was triggered. Any suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: You don't need to invoke `.map` function at all, hence you map the same object again. Also, adding a `try-catch` to the entire statement won't work in the sense of finding the actual problem. You should add `try-catch` foe each of the block find to what's going around.

Answer (score 0):

In the body of your method you pass to `map` (a lambda in your example), you can add a try-catch block around your code just like in any other method.

The purpose of `orElseThrow` method of Optional is just to throw an exception if your Optional is empty. The method you pass to it should construct the exception object you want to throw (e.g. `RuntimeException::new`), and then it gets thrown.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to look into the `Optional` class a bit more and then maybe post the code that works without Optionals using the try...catch, i.e. the complete method and what you want to do. For now, I'll answer by taking a guess.

Assuming you have a method like the following, where you want to test and return an object, while logging and ignoring any exceptions in the wrapped validation logic:

```
static class Service {

    public <T> Predicate<T> getAndValidate(final T t) {
        return null;
    }
}

static <T> T test(final T t) {
    final Service service = null; // need to initialize properly

    // code without optional
    try {
        if (t != null) {
            if (service.getAndValidate(t).test(t)) {
                return t;
            }
        }
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Now, you can have the same code a bit less verbose by using `Optional`. You don't need a `map` with the identity function, you can simply use `filter` and wrap the service call with try...catch.

```
static <T> T test(final T t) {
    final Service service = null;

    return Optional.ofNullable(t)
            .filter(p -> {
                try { // you can also wrap it with try..catch
                    return service.getAndValidate(p).test(p);
                } catch (final Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return false; // filter element on exception
                }
            }).orElse(null);

}
```

However, I would rethink this method design. First of all, catching a `Exception` instead of a specific subclass is usually not a good idea, especially not if you simply choose to ignore it (and only print the stack trace). If you can not handle the exception in a meaningful way, why not let the caller handle it further up the stack? I would consider returning an `Optional<T>` instead of `null` (that is the intention of `Optional` anyway):

```
static <T> Optional<T> test(final T t) {
    final Service service = null;

    return Optional.ofNullable(t)
            .filter(p -> service.getAndValidate(p).test(p));

}
```

Alternatively, you can also choose to throw a meaningful exception (maybe even create your own subclass of RuntimeException):

```
static <T> T test(final T t) {
    final Service service = null;

    return Optional.ofNullable(t)
            .filter(p -> service.getAndValidate(p).test(p))
            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("The validation was not successful"));

}
```